# firefox/IE statusbar are in front of FLEX page

Tags: apache-flex, internet-explorer, firefox, statusbar

I created the page in FLEX, but i have problem with scroller (the page content) and the bottom status bar from IE/firefox. They are easily overlapping each other (with statusbar in the front - hiding the content of the page) - is there any way to read the height of these elements regardles of the browser (to change 'paddingbottom' accordingly ) ? (I know that disabling them is prohibited from security reasons).

Code:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="800" minHeight="600" 
           xmlns:components="components.*"
           xmlns:men="components.pages.admin_subpage.*"
           backgroundColor="#000000"
           creationComplete="init()"
           applicationComplete="application1_applicationCompleteHandler(event)"
           skinClass="BackgroundColor"
           >
<s:Scroller id="scroll" left="2" right="2" top="2" bottom="2"> 
    <s:VGroup id="tresc"
              textAlign="center" horizontalAlign="center" gap="10" horizontalCenter="0" bottom="0" paddingBottom="10" top="20" width="100%" height="100%"
              gap.schowaneLogowanie="0">
        <s:HGroup width="100%" paddingLeft="20" paddingTop="20" horizontalAlign="center" textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" width.schowaneLogowanie="91%" gap.schowaneLogowanie="0" paddingLeft.schowaneLogowanie="0" paddingRight.wysunieteLogowanie="15">
            <s:Group width="100%">
                <components:logo id="logo"  width="100%"  width.schowaneLogowanie="100%"/>
                <s:HGroup width="100%" verticalAlign.schowaneLogowanie="middle" height.schowaneLogowanie="122" gap="0">

                    <mx:Spacer width="83%"/>
                    <s:TextInput height="30" contentBackgroundAlpha="0.3" width="12%" id="searchText" keyDown="hgr_keyDownHandler(event)" text="Search..." borderVisible.schowaneLogowanie="false"/>
                    <s:Button height="32" alpha="0.8" width="5%" click="button1_clickHandler(event)" label="Go"/>
                </s:HGroup>
            </s:Group>
        </s:HGroup>
        <men:menuTest id="menu" width="100%" textAlign="center"/> //Whole content of page is set here
        <components:stopka id="stopka"  bottom="5" left="5" right="5" />
        <!--<components:menu currentState="wysunietaTresc" textAlign="center" width="100%"/>-->
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Scroller> 
</s:Application>
```

I deleted most of the  stuff from example. I have tried changing application and scroller heigth to precent one, but it didnt help.

You can see the page example here: http://cerber.cs.put.poznan.pl/~inf84884/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the height of the application as percentage ??
that would put up a scrollbar in the flex application, and also you can see the whole content by scrolling down.

Would you please care to share your code?
Also, a few more details would be nice.

Comment: I posted it, its a bit messy - but im only interested in application and scroller component. I can manually set padding bottom but it will loook horrible in Chrome browser (without any status bar).